# I can't compile, on my library SafeMath it says "parsererror: function, vairable, struct or modifier declaration expected, please help me

Tags: contract-development, compiler, remix-tests

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.2;

contract Token {
    mapping(address => uint) public balances;
    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint)) public allowance;
    uint public totalSupply = 5000000000 * 10**6;
    string public name = "Test";
    string public symbol = "TTt";
    uint public decimals = 6;
    
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint value);
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint value);
 
    constructor () {
        balances[msg.sender] = totalSupply;
    }
    
    function balanceOf(address owner) public view returns(uint) {
        return balances[owner];
    }  
    
    function transfer(address to, uint value) public returns(bool) {
        require(balanceOf(msg.sender) >= value, 'balances too low');
        balances[to] += value;
        balances[msg.sender] -= value;
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, to, value);
        return true;
    }
    
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint value) public returns(bool) {
        require(balanceOf(from) >= value, 'balance too low');
        require(allowance[from][msg.sender] >= value, 'allowance too low');
        balances[to] += value;
        balances[from] -= value;
        emit Transfer(from, to, value);
        return true;
    }
    
    function approve(address spender, uint value) public returns(bool) {
        allowance[msg.sender][spender] = value;
        emit Approval(msg.sender, spender, value);
        return true;
    
    }


library SafeMath {
function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        uint256 c = a + b;
        require(c >= a, "SafeMath: addition overflow");

        return c;
     }

function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b, string memory errorMessage) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        require(b <= a, errorMessage);
        uint256 c = a - b;

        return c;
    }

function mul(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        // Gas optimization: this is cheaper than requiring 'a' not being zero, but the
        // benefit is lost if 'b' is also tested.
        // See: https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/pull/522
        if (a == 0) {
            return 0;
        }

        uint256 c = a * b;
        require(c / a == b, "SafeMath: multiplication overflow");

        return c;

    }     
function div(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        return div(a, b, "SafeMath: division by zero");
    }

function div(uint256 a, uint256 b, string memory errorMessage) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        require(b > 0, errorMessage);
        uint256 c = a / b;
        // assert(a == b * c + a % b); // There is no case in which this doesn't hold

        return c;
    }

function mod(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        return mod(a, b, "SafeMath: modulo by zero");
    }

function mod(uint256 a, uint256 b, string memory errorMessage) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        require(b != 0, errorMessage);
        return a % b;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit difficult to tell from your code here but two things of note. First point, if using a library in your contract you also need to declare it

```
contract myContract {
  using SafeMath for uint;
```

Second point, since compiler v0.8.0 and above, overflow protection is default behaviour in solidity so SafeMath library is redundant.